# What is the difference between kubuntu and installing kde on ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu

If I were to install kde in Ubuntu with the recommended applications, would I get the same thing as installing Kubuntu, or does Kubuntu have additional apps or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If you do not remove the ubuntu desktop you will end up with 2 operating systems that show programs from both desktop. Example:you will have both gedit and kate as editors.

If you 1st remove the ubuntu desktop and then add kubuntu desktop you will end up with KDE. There might be left over configuration files from the ubuntu desktop but you should not notice any difference as when you installed kUbuntu. All the ubuntu software will be removed and all you will see is KDE.

Comment: How would one "1st remove the ubuntu desktop and then add kubuntu desktop"?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FromUbuntuToKubuntu